# Error When installing mysql from gems Mac 10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, installation

I have seen variants of this question but none of them are the right answer (so far).

I am trying to install mysql from rubygems and get the following:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I have tried the arguments like -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config and still get the same result.

Manual instal from the mysql website installs, but I cannot start it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got MySQL installed but you don't have the development headers for it. You may need to download and install a version that has those.

I'm a big fan of using [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) to do this, though this will leave you with a slightly irregular name for things as MacPorts calls it mysql_config5 instead. I usually symlink this to fix the name:

```
ln -s /opt/local/bin/mysql_config5 /opt/local/bin/mysql_config
```

You can do this for any of the binaries with unusual names like `mysql5` and `mysqladmin5`.

Comment: I am using it for Rails dev (beginner). Stupid question, this will not be a problem to do it with MacPorts?

Comment: MacPorts is a source based install, so you get all the development headers as part of the package. Many binary installs are missing this sort of thing to save space. You could also try [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and see what works best for you.